# Symfony view.yml vs use_javascript/use_stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, symfony1

Which is better?
View.yml for each module and/or action
or
just adding use_javascript/use_stylesheet in the views?

I'm asking because I heard view.yml is slower, but some plugins need view.yml to contain all the javascripts and stylesheets (e.g. to combine and minify)

Answer (score 1):

"but some plugins need view.yml to contain all the javascripts and stylesheets (e.g. to combine and minify)" Correct. For minifying using view.yml is very useful. Furthermore, I prefer to use view.yml because I can get a quick overview of what stylesheets/javascript a template is using.

view.yml isn't slower, as long as you use the appropriate caching mechanisms. It's only in dev it's slower. Remember that when you're in production and you change view.yml it won't be updated until you clear the cache.

Let's look at a quick example:

```
contractCreateSuccess:
  javascripts:
    - hint.js
    - /jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
    - /jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js
    - /jquery/plugins/ui.selectmenu.js
    - /sfFormExtraPlugin/js/jquery.autocompleter.js
  stylesheets:
    - /jquery/css/Aristo/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css
    - /sfFormExtraPlugin/css/jquery.autocompleter.css
    - /jquery/plugins/ui.selectmenu.css

yourContractViewPrintSuccess:
  layout: print

agreementViewPrintSuccess:
  layout: print 
contractUploadFileSuccess:
  javascripts:
    - /jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
    - /jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js
  stylesheets:
    - /jquery/css/Aristo/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css
    - /jquery/plugins/ui.selectmenu.css
parnterCreateSuccess:
  javascripts:
    - /jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
    - /jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js
  stylesheets:
    - /jquery/css/Aristo/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css
```

I feel that's much neater and easier to read than using the aforementioned functions. :-)

Comment: what caching mechanisms would that entail? I'm just using defaults right now but also exploring sfAPCCache for projects that support APC